Im unsure wether i am actually pure from menses
Assalamu alaikum, my period usually lasts for 6 days and on the 7th day when i came back from outside and checked my pad there was nothing on the pad only a small yellow dot. So i thought that my period was supposed to end at any time by now, so i made istinja and put on another pad and waited for 30 minutes and i did not see anything so i made ghusl and prayed duhr-asr in salatul qasr because im currently traveling, but when i went out again with my family i saw another brown discharge on my pad. Then i realized that i did not move the whole time when checking for the sign of purity and my underwear was a-bit oversized so most likely the discharge couldn’t get on it and i did not wipe to check before taking ghusl did i rush in making ghusl and can i pray?
